# Installing Epson print driver gives 404 on Ubuntu.com

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am installing the generic Epson print driver from Epson here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX. When installing with Ubuntu software centre I get an immediate error to check network. On looking at the detail of the error it appears there is a 404 on
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg-dev_1.17.5ubuntu5.3_all.deb

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is with the Software Center, but you can install the driver without it.

Create `Epson` folder in your home folder and place there deb driver files.

Then tun in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Epson/*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```